# Ruby Data Structure - Queue with Maximum

Tags: ruby, data-structures

I'm looking for a Ruby data structure with the following characteristics and am hoping to not have to roll my own:

1. First-in-first-out (i.e. a queue)
2. Allows specifying a max length
3. When the queue reaches capacity, the new item is pushed in and the oldest item is discarded.

I thought [SizedQueue](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/thread/rdoc/SizedQueue.html) might have done the job but it doesn't satisfy criteria #3 as it blocks pushing when the max length is reached.

Anyone know of such a beast in a well maintained library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a circular queue or a ring buffer.

[cbuffer](http://rubygems.org/gems/cbuffer) is close, but still throws if it exceeds the available space.

I've found a few other implementations as sample code but not, up to this point, packaged as a gem. One was [this RingBuffer snippet](https://rubyforge.org/snippet/detail.php?type=snippet&id=78). This is perhaps a rather minimalist implementation and probably needs a bit of work.

[This location](http://www.koders.com/ruby/fid4567E39C011F7064117A60EEC2625B6B345EB77B.aspx) seems to contain a fairly complete implementation of a RingBuffer.

Comment: Thanks for giving me two new search terms :-)

Comment: A "circular array" was another term used by a colleague of mine way back when, especially if the purpose (say, stack vs. queue) was less than specific.

Answer (score 1):

The last two links in JasonTrue's answer are dead now, but I found (possibly the same) RingBuffer snippet here: https://gist.github.com/eerohele/1904422

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one https://gist.github.com/julik/a4c0b88abc17922f4f2a1a01a6bba530

Use it like so:

```
ring = Ring.new(4)
ring.pos #=> 0
ring << :a # fills first element
ring.pos #=> 1
ring << :b << :c << :d # fills the rest
ring.to_a # [:a, :b, :c, :d] - Array of elements from the current position
ring.next #=> :a 
ring.to_a # [:b, :c, :d, :e] - Position shifted
ring << :z #=> overwrites :b and advances position
ring.to_a #=> [:c, :d, :a, :z]
```